# How to keep table name when inner joining related tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database

I am new to SQL and wonder how to select nested tables.
I have two tables like this:

**sensors**

| sensor_id | model_no | location_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| int | varchar | int |

**locations**

| location_id | name | location | radius |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int | varchar | point | int |

They are linked with `foreign key`. Currently, I select using

```sql
SELECT sensors.*, locations.*
FROM sensors INNER JOIN locations
ON sensors.location_id = locations.location_id;
```

to get the data from both like this:

```json
{
  "sensor_id": 1,
  "model_no": "some string",
  "location_id": 2,
  "name": "Berlin",
  "location": {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 3
  },
  "radius": 1000
}
```

I wonder if there is any way I can keep the location data grouped as its own object like this:

```json
{
  "sensor_id": 1,
  "model_no": "some string",
  "location": {
    "name": "Berlin",
    "location": {
      "x": 3,
      "y": 3
    },
    "radius": 1000
  }
}
```

I am using MySQL 8 with mysql npm package to execute the queries. I know I can modify the response using javascript but wonder if it can be done directly in the query, and if so, is it better or worse for performance?

Comment: *Currently, I select using .. to get the data from both like this* Shown query cannot return shown JSON. Maybe JSON is the query output interpretation made by the client? *if there is any way I can keep the location data grouped as its own object like this* MySQL can create this JSON easily. But it cannot return the rowset which will be interpreted as shown JSON - query output is always 2D-table.

Comment: @Akina I noticed this after trying the queries elsewhere, that the location is actually split up by the js client. I also saw the npm mysql package has an option "nestedTables" you can use to achieve something similar to what I want but not quite. I think for now I'll reformat the response in javascript to my liking. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 
           'sensor_id', sensor_id, 
           'model_no', model_no,
           'location', JSON_OBJECT( 
                           'name', name,
                           'location', JSON_OBJECT(
                                           'x', CAST(ST_X(location) AS SIGNED),
                                           'y', CAST(ST_Y(location) AS SIGNED) 
                                           ),
                           'radius', radius 
                           )
                  ) as JSON_output
FROM sensors
JOIN locations USING (location_id);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b17dfa3069b4bb9345a9e99e8b893121

Comment: Thanks, this works like I want! However, is there any way to have the json return the data in the order specified when creating the JSON_OBJECT? For example, for your query the response should be {sensor_id, model_no, location} but this is not always the case. the id may come at any "index" in the JSON. I know there is no order in JSON keys, but to keep it clean, I would like the id to be the first key. This is an example response I got. Can't seem to find any logic to the order: `{"ph": 7.5, "data_id": 1, "temperature": 20.6, "conductivity": 28425}`

Comment: @NoobishProgrammer *is there any way to have the json return the data in the order specified when creating the JSON_OBJECT?* Your need makes no sense. The object properties are always sorted alphabetically because they're identified by property name and not by property position. Rather than the array in which the relative elements posession makes sense and is not changed during saving and retrieving. If relative position makes sense for you then use an array.

Comment: ” The object properties are always sorted alphabetically because they're identified by property name and not by property position” - I’m totally fine with this. But it seems like thats not the case as you could see by the exemple response I got. I dont need it to be in that order, just curious of how it decided the order and if i could modify it.

Comment: @NoobishProgrammer Please distinguish JSON-type value and string-type value which stores JSON. When you deal with JSON column then the object properties are sorted unconditionally - this is defined by JSON storing, its inner binary format. Also the most part of JSON functions performs such resorting. But when you deal with string-type column then JSON value placed into it is stored as common text and, hence, is not resorted - you get strictly the same value which was placed into the column.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You must manually label each column; you cannot get the desired result *and* use `*`.

A small consolation prize:  If you change

```
ON sensors.location_id = locations.location_id;
```

to

```
USING(location_id)
```

There will be only one `location_id` column.